# Terraform split and store last position of given string

Tags: terraform

I would like to split below value and store last value into variables in terraform. The number of values after / will be different, sometimes there will be 5 values .../value5 etc. What I wanted is to have the last value after /

```
value_1: /test/test2/test3
value_2: /test/test2

name    = split("/",var.value_1)[]
```

Comment: found a different solution. used reverse function. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would [basename](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/basename) be more appropriate in the use case?

> basename("/test/test2/test3")